# Profiling number of garbage-collected object instances per class

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am looking for a tool that can provide VisuaVM-like profiling about live objects, but in non-GUI mode.

The Visual VM functionality I am referring, is accessed by going to the "Profiler" tab and clicking "Memory".

By setting a profile preset of "Profile object allocations and GC" for ever 1 objects (all objects). This gives me exactly what I need in an auto-refreshing view, which I can filter for the class that interests me.

However, I want to be able to export the table of "live objects" to a text file, for every snapshot that is taken (Visual VM refreshes every one seconds). Obviously, pointing and clicking cannot possibly be a solution...

Anyone know of such a "command-line" profiler?

I have been looking at jmap which provides heap dumps, but it is too costly (the dump takes too long, I am just interested in the number of objects).

There is a commercial tool called YourKit but I don't know whether it can do what I need (and also seems rather expensive for the type of "one-off" usage I need it for).

If I could use VisualVM as-is, but have it append the output to a file (instead of refreshing its GUI) it'd be perfect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Class Histograms are what you look for. You could collect the histograms in regular intervals and this will show you **number of objects** of each class and **occupied space**. You can then parse the text output yourself in order to:

- compare two histograms to see instance allocation/deallocation
- filter by a class name
- monitor space occupation of class instances over time

Collect class histogram with `jmap -histo $pid.`